# Yii2 - migration can't be applied

Tags: yii2, migration, database-migration

I wanted to apply migrations, but it won't let me do that.

cmd looks like this:

```
D:\web\website>yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.35)

Total 5 new migrations to be applied:
        sjaakp\pluto\migrations\m000000_000000_init
        m140506_102106_rbac_init
        m170907_052038_rbac_add_index_on_auth_assignment_user_id
        m180523_151638_rbac_updates_indexes_without_prefix
        m200409_110543_rbac_update_mssql_trigger

Apply the above migrations? (yes|no) [no]:
D:\web\website>
```

It won't let me type 'yes' to apply to the migrations.

Anyone an Idea what I can do?
Thanks.

Comment: are you on widnows?

Comment: I dont know wath is the problem with your terminal, but You can do it by applying `yes`  default using with `--interactive=0` in migration command like fallowing: 
`yii migrate  --interactive=0 --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations`

Comment: @ustmaestro, thanks for the answer. It helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ustmaestro gave a helpful answer:

> I dont know wath is the problem with your terminal, but You can do it
>   by applying yes default using with --interactive=0 in migration
>   command like following: **yii migrate --interactive=0
>   --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations**

Answer (score 0):

You can customize migration to run without confirm by setting **interactive** mode to false.
So add `--interactive=0`  to your migration command.

For more information see [Customizing Migrations](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-migrations#customizing-migrations).